# Trying to combine two (2) statements together

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-arrayformula

I am trying to pull data based off of selections made in a dropdown list, and would like to combine two (2) statements/formulas into one. Separately, they both work well and achieve what I want them to, but I would like to combine them so that the data being returned shows up in one place.

`=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(Options!C9="Cyclon",IMPORTRANGE("1nvZwulmKkuhBNNgltZzR7VYqjrx0LMWuT7v9Kpjnn10","'Standard, Cylon Backbox'!A:F"),IMPORTRANGE("1nvZwulmKkuhBNNgltZzR7VYqjrx0LMWuT7v9Kpjnn10","'Floating Backbox'!A:F")))`

`=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(Options!C3="AE",IMPORTRANGE("1nvZwulmKkuhBNNgltZzR7VYqjrx0LMWuT7v9Kpjnn10","'Arcade Cabinet'!A:F"),IMPORTRANGE("1nvZwulmKkuhBNNgltZzR7VYqjrx0LMWuT7v9Kpjnn10","'Xtra Cabinet'!A:F")))`

Both of these formulas/statements work great on their own, but I am unable to combine them into one statement so that all of the data being called for by BOTH statements can be pulled into one sheet together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can combine the two `importrange()` calls with an [{ array expression }](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/6208276), but since you are using open-ended range references, there will be many blank rows in between the two data tables. Assuming that column `A` contains a value of the same type on all non-blank rows in all data ranges, you can use `query()` to weed out blank rows like this:

```
=query( 
  { 
    importrange("1nvZwulmKkuhBNNgltZzR7VYqjrx0LMWuT7v9Kpjnn10", 
      if( 
        Options!C9 = "Cyclon", 
        "'Standard, Cylon Backbox'!A:F", 
        "'Floating Backbox'!A:F" 
      ) 
    ); 
    importrange("1nvZwulmKkuhBNNgltZzR7VYqjrx0LMWuT7v9Kpjnn10", 
      if( 
        Options!C3 = "AE", 
        "'Arcade Cabinet'!A:F", 
        "'Xtra Cabinet'!A:F" 
      ) 
    ) 
  }, 
  "where Col1 is not null", 
  0 
)
```

Alternatively, replace the open-ended range references `A:F` with something like `A1:F42`, and drop the `query()` wrapper in the formula.